# How can I automatically export csv and send it to a database or textfile

Tags: database, csv, wordpress

I have to make a mailing list to which you can subscribe in Wordpress. I've found a WP plugin in which you have a form with two fields, name and email. These are being saved into a csv file which I can export with a press of a button, literally. I want to automatically export this csv file into a database or a simple text file, which keeps updating and adding new subscribers.

The plugin I'm using now is called "Mail Subscribe List".
I'm using Wordpress version 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a cron job to automatically do stuff periodically. To do this on windows or linux us the 'at' command. Google it for details on how to do it.

Basically you will need to create a php file to do the export, then set up a cron job to run the php at whatever intervals you require.